# excel show date when warehouse will be empty (including forecast delivery-plan)

Tags: google-sheets

I have a warehouse calculation sheet:

- In line 2: It is tracking sales and also giving a stock-forecast for every day future.
- In line 3: Its possible to plan deliveries and stock correction

Now in an overview sheet I would like to know the next date when the warehouse will be empty. I've got this function, but it is showing a date in past, but it should ignore past dates. How can I do this dynamically?

```
=index(filter(NA$2:$2;NA3:3<0);1)
```

Maybe sth. with `match()`?

[image]

Comment: Should this have a google-spreadsheet tag?

Comment: Answers will definitely depend on whether the workbook is truly an Excel file, or is a web spreadsheet run with Google Sheets, since they have different formulas and capabilities. I think OP is using Google Sheets, and thus the excel tag should be removed...

Comment: sorry I thought they are mostly the same. I removed excel-tag.

Comment: Did either answer to your question here resolve the issue?

Comment: @tehhowch no, I see its working in your sheet, but I get different errors or wrong result. Thankyou anyway for the help! I have to investigate more in depth what is "wrong" in my sheet and how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=filter($2:$2;3:3<0;$2:$2>=TODAY())
=INDEX(filter($2:$2;3:3<0;$2:$2>=TODAY());1)
```

Comment: I entered it in I3 and the row data starts in L3. L2 is 1.1.17; l3 is 2.1.17 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Your initial condition:

```
=index(filter(NA$2:$2; NA3:3<0); 1)
```

Only filters the input range based on the expected supply. To also exclude past dates, where dates are in row 2, add this as another filter condition:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(NA$2:$2; NA3:3<0; NA$2:$2>=TODAY()); 1)
```

---

In my example here I have dates in row 1 and supply in row 2:
[image: a mockup (with locale en-us)]

Comment: my dates are in row 2, the stock-quantity is in row 3. I always get this error doesnt matter where I put this formula "NV   >>>  
in the evaluation of "filter" no hits were found"

Comment: @KrystianManthey are your dates actually parsed as dates by the sheet? I see you have some custom format with `.` but it is not clear if that was entered `07.03` or `2018/03/07` and then a custom date time format is applied to render it as `07.03`. please clarify if the values in row 2 are truly dates or just formatted numbers.

Comment: they are dates like 01.01.2018 but you see only 01.01.

Comment: @KrystianManthey are there projected deficits in the future? If there are no deficits in the future, then it will return the `#NA` error

Comment: yes there are. Thankyou very much for helping anyway! :-)